# Error 0xc000000e when booting

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, dualboot

My laptop has a primary SSD with Windows 10 on it
I installed a new SSD on which I installed another Windows 10, but wanted to keep the old one on the other disk. Everything was working fine : the Windows boot manager let me choose which installation of Windows I want to start.

My partitions look like this:
[image: Partition manager]

Disk 0 is the old SSD
Disk 1 is the new one

Then, as long as I "restarted" my computer, everything was fine : the boot manager let me choose between the 2 Windows, and if I choose the new one, it boots correctly.

But one time I didn't restart, I stopped Windows. When starting back, I got this blue screen, even before the Windows boot manager (sorry it's in French):
[image: Blue screen]

Then I cannot boot anymore. I find out that pressing "Esc" open the BIOS, then if I exit without making changes, then the Windows boot manager will correctly show up and I can boot Windows

The only fact to access the BIOS seems to unlock something
I tried many times and always the same result : restart is ok, but stop+start is not.

Is the some way to solve this problem?

Comment: The new disk can it work without an EFI partition. Reinstall Windows to the new disk and disconnect the old first.

Comment: i didn't want to open my laptop again. Instead, I tried to change the boot sequence from (boot manager > ssd1 > ssd2) to (ssd2 > boot manager > ssd1). I booted anyway on boot manager, but the problem disappeared. I configured back (boot manager > ssd1 > ssd2), and the problem did not came back. Does this make any sense?

Comment: about licences, I guess it's the same. I installed the new WIndows using a USB stick, and windows has been automatically activated, I guess it found the existing licence?